Quotient ring of linear ideal
Let $K$ be a characteristic 0 field. Let $I=(L_1,...,L_r)$ be an ideal of polynomial ring $K[x_0,...,x_n]$, where $L_i\in K[x_0,...,x_n]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $1$. Let us assume $\text{dim}(K[x_0,...,x_n]/I)=r\geq 1$, then how to show $K[x_0,...,x_n]/I\simeq K[y_1,...,y_r]$, where $K[y_1,...,y_r]$ is a polynomial ring?
When $r=1$, it is not difficult to see, since for $L_1=a_0x_0+\dots+a_nx_n$, if $a_0\neq 0$, then $K[x_0,...,x_n]/(a_0x_0+\dots+a_nx_n)=K[b_1x_1+\dots+b_nx_n,x_1,...,x_n]=K[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $b_i=\frac{-a_i}{a_0}$. I think for $r\geq 2$ one could also do the same operation by induction, however, I don't know how to show it in a clear way.

Let $L_i=\sum a_{ij}x_j$ and $A_{r\times n}=(a_{ij})$.
Assume the $L_i$'s are linearly independent.
By suitable change of orders of $x_i$, we have an invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$PA=(I_r~ B).$$
Then $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(L_1,\ldots,L_r)\cong K[x_{r+1},\ldots,x_n]$.
